# арифметическое действие mysql c условием

Tags: mysql

Как правильно произвести арифметическое действие на ячейку с условием  id_nds=1

```
SELECT id_parts, id_nds, 
(cost*(18/118(id_nds=1))) as nds,
id_orders_tehnika, id_tehnika, name, count, note, cost, date, date_give FROM 
spare_parts
```

Comment: Mysql выдаёт ошибку и ругается на (cost*(18/118(id_nds=1)))

Comment: Ну наверное между 118 и скобкой надо какой-нить плюс или там звёздочку поставить... а если там чисто умножить-поделить, то и скобки не нужны... как бы...

Comment: Вот я раньше вот этим запросом пользовался (hours*(100+50*(id_service=2))) AS earned, работало! но тут я умножал на число, а не ячейку

Comment: @ArtyomVermilion Вот именно _умножали_ если поставить знак умножения то будет работать `( cost*(18/118)*(id_nds=1) )`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте условные конструкции правильно: [MySQL IF()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php)

```
SELECT
`id_parts`,
`id_nds`,
IF (`id_nds` = 1, `cost` * (18/118), 0) AS `nds`
`id_orders_tehnika`,
`id_tehnika`,
`name`,
`count`,
`note`,
`cost`,
`date`,
`date_give`
FROM `spare_parts`;
```

В этом случае выборка будет подсчитывать НДС в случае, если поле `id_nds` равно 1, и будет подставлять 0 в противном случае

Comment: `IF` безусловно делает формулу более наглядной, но в MySQL оператор сравнения `=` выдает 0 или 1 в зависимости от истинности условия, поэтому изначальный пример ТС из вопроса так же был полностью рабочим, если бы он не забыл поставить знак умножения

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен, в результате будет то же самое

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался:

```
(cost*18/118*(id_nds=1)) as nds
```